# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 17: invalid start byte (heroku)

Tags: python, utf-8, heroku, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['irregular_verbs'])
def irregular_verbs_word(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите слово:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, irregular_verbs)

def irregular_verbs(message):
    word = message.text
    text = "неправильный глагол не найден ❌"

    file = open('irregular_verbs_list.txt').readlines()
    for i in iter(file):
        if word in i:
            text_words = i.split()
            text = ("*ГЛАГОЛ:*   " + '_'+text_words[0]+'_' + '\n' + 
            "*II форма (PAST SIMPLE):*   " + '_'+text_words[1]+'_' + '\n' + 
            "*III форма (PAST PARTICIPLE)*   " + '_'+text_words[2]+'_' + '\n' + 
            "*ПЕРЕВОД:*   " + '_'+text_words[3]+'_')

    bot.reply_to(message, text, parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

после запуска на компьютере все работает хорошо, но после запуска на сервере heroku, получаю ошибку:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 17: invalid start
> byte

Как это исправить?

Comment: В функции open укажите кодировку вашего файла

Comment: file = open('irregular_verbs_list.txt', encoding='ANSI').readlines()

**unknown encoding: ANSI**

Comment: Потому что ANSI — это название целого семейства разных кодировок, а в вашем случае ANSI-кодировка это скорее всего cp1251

Comment: в файле записаны строки как  "be was/were been Быть". Какая это кодировка?

Comment: с этим разобрался, бот работает, он выводит латинский текст, но кирилицу выводит другими символами как "Èäòè". Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Ну так кодировку cp1251 укажите всё-таки

Comment: хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь!